# C Programming: += vs =+

Tags: c, operators

My professor and I are engaging in a bit of a debate about the += operator in C. He says that += or =+ will work, but he is not certain why =+ works.

```
int main()
{
    int i = 0, myArray[5] = {1,1,1,1,1};

    while(i < 5)
    {
            myArray[i] += 3 + i;
            printf("%d\n", myArray[i]);
            i++;
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

The output will yield 4, 5, 6, 7, 8. Changing the += operator to =+ yields the same results. However -= does not do the same as =- (which is obvious as it treats the 3 as a 3).

So C gurus:

- Why does this work with =+?
- How does a C compiler treat =+ versus +=?

Comment: Using what compiler does it yield the same results???

Comment: Changing the operator to =+ yields `3,4,5,6,7`.  Perhaps you forgot to save the source file before recompiling or something?

Comment: Your professor is incompetent and should retire.

Answer (score 23):

He is wrong; `+=` is completely different from `=+`.

The expression `x =+ 3` is parsed as `x = (+3)`.
Here, `+` becomes the (rather useless) unary `+` operator.  (the opposite of negation)

The expression `x =- 3` is parsed as `x = (-3)`, using the unary negation operator.

Answer (score 14):

Your professor is remembering *ancient* versions of C in which `=+`, `=-`, `=*` etc did in fact mean the same thing as `+=`, `-=`, `*=` etc.  (We're talking older than the version generally referred to as "K&R" here.  Version 6 UNIX, if memory serves.)

In *current* versions of C, they do not mean the same thing; the versions with the equals sign first will be parsed as if there was a space in between the equals and whatever comes after.  This happens to produce a valid program (albeit not a program that does what you expect) for `=-` and `=+` because `-` and `+` can be used as unary operators.

`=*` or `=/` could be used to settle the argument.  `a *= 3` will multiply `a` by three, and `a /= 3` will divide it by three, but `a =* 3` is a semantic error (because unary `*` can only be applied to pointers) and `a =/ 3` is a syntax error (because `/` can *not* be used as an unary operator).

Comment: Yes, if you look at the code in the Lions book, you will see that it spells the operator as `=+` (it also contains some other examples of C from the period, like using the `.` operator on non-struct types).

Comment: Here is the B manual (C was adapted from B) at: http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/kbman.html. It shows the asingment operators with the equal sign in the first position.

Comment: =+ was changed to += in the move from Unix version 6 to Unix version 7 some time in the 70's, when many other changes were made to the C language, largely from the effort to port it to machines other than the PDP-11.

Comment: `a =* 3` is not a syntax error, it's a dereferencing the integer value 3 as if it was a pointer. Most compiler will warn or even generate an error because of type violation but a syntax error it is not. Some very old compiler will even accept it.

Comment: @tristopia I suppose I used the term 'syntax error' imprecisely.  It is, however, an unambiguously invalid program per the standard; a compiler that accepts the program (with or without a warning) is not a conforming compiler. (N1570: section 6.5.3.2p2 "The operand of the unary `*` operator shall have pointer type." That's a "shall" clause in a "constraints" section, which must be diagnosed per 5.1.1.3.)

Comment: You're right that conforming compiler will not accept that construct, with old compiler I meant pre-ansi K&R compiler.

Answer (score 3):

Code

```
myArray[i] += 3 + i;
```

will yield `myArray[i] = myArray[i] + 3 + i;`

whereas

```
myArray[i] =+ 3 + i;
```

yields `myArray[i] = 3 + i`

that's what I got.

Answer (score 1):

`+` is also a unary operator as is `-`.

Comment: You're missing the logical leap that makes this actually answer the question.

Comment: For questions like this one (non API questions) I like to provide the least specific answer that will nudge the poster in the direction of the solution. Everything I've learned and remembered I've arrived at myself. Everything I've forgotten I was spoonfed.